# Is it possible to limit all the queries with tenant_id in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

One possible way to isolate tenants is to add `tenant_id` to every table, and scope every request with that field.

But you have to be very carefull and put that in every SQL query.

I wonder if there's a way to tell PostgreSQL to do that automatically? Something like

```
scope tenant_id = 'foo'

select * from my_table -- tenant_id = 'foo' should be added automatically
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use views in conjunction with custom configuration parameters, example:

```
create table customers_table(id serial primary key, tenant_id int, name text);
insert into customers_table (tenant_id, name) values
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(1, 'c'),
(2, 'd');

create view customers as
select *
from customers_table
where tenant_id = current_setting('glb.tenant_id')::int;
```

Use the view instead of the table in your select queries. You have to set the custom configuration parameter to have queries run:

```
select * from customers;

ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "glb.tenant_id"

set glb.tenant_id to 1;
select * from customers;

 id | tenant_id | name 
----+-----------+------
  1 |         1 | a
  3 |         1 | c
(2 rows)
```